# Reading PGM Image in C (Not Reading File Correctly)

Tags: c, eclipse, pgm

I'm using files, [pgm.c](http://sun.iwu.edu/~shelley/sie/zoo/journal/pgm.c.html) and [pgm.h](http://sun.iwu.edu/~shelley/sie/zoo/journal/pgm.h.html) to read in a PGM image file, and then my program will manipulate the file (grayscale, rotation, etc).

However, I can't get the file to read properly.  When I use:

```
   PGMImage* img = (PGMImage*)malloc(sizeof(PGMImage));
   char iName1[256];
   printf("Enter the filename of your PGM image:\n");
   scanf("%s", iName1);
   getPGMfile(iName1, &img);
```

The console returns the type, width, height and maximum value  of the image.  However, the width is never correct.  It's usually 0 (and one time it was 56, way off) whether I'm using a .pgm file I found online or one I made myself.  I've even tried hard-coding the width of the image, but even so, it causes the program the crash.  The width should be read in pgm.c, under the getPGMfile function:

```
void getPGMfile (char filename[], PGMImage *img)
 {
   FILE *in_file;
   char ch;
   int row, col, type;
   int ch_int;

   in_file = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (in_file == NULL)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s\n\n", filename);
     exit(8);
   }

   printf("\nReading image file: %s\n", filename);

   /*determine pgm image type (only type three can be used)*/
   ch = getc(in_file);
   if(ch != 'P')
   {
      printf("ERROR(1): Not valid pgm/ppm file type\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   ch = getc(in_file);
   /*convert the one digit integer currently represented as a character to
     an integer(48 == '0')*/
   type = ch - 48;
   printf("Type: %d", type);
   if((type != 2) && (type != 3) && (type != 5) && (type != 6))
   {
      printf("ERROR(2): Not valid pgm/ppm file type\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   while(getc(in_file) != '\n');             /* skip to end of line*/

   while (getc(in_file) == '#')              /* skip comment lines */
   {
     while (getc(in_file) != '\n');          /* skip to end of comment line */
   }

   /*there seems to be a difference between color and b/w.  This line is needed
     by b/w but doesn't effect color reading...*/
   fseek(in_file, -1, SEEK_CUR);             /* backup one character*/

   fscanf(in_file,"%d", &((*img).width));
   fscanf(in_file,"%d", &((*img).height));
   fscanf(in_file,"%d", &((*img).maxVal));

   //I omitted the rest, but it can be seen in the link above
```

I have no idea what's causing these errors.  I'm using Eclipse and MinGW GCC on Windows 7 (64-bit).  My instructor couldn't help me solve this, so I'm hoping you can! :)

To summarize: The width of the PGM image is always read incorrectly, anything done with the file afterwards causes the executable to stop working.  Hard-coding the width also causes the the executable to stop working.

Comment: getpgm shouldn't be passed the address of your pointer, but rather just the pointer according to the header file:  getPGMfile(iName1, img)

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the function calls provided by netpbm http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/libnetpbm.html

Comment: @Magn3s1um: +1, except make it an answer since it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

getpgm shouldn't be passed the address of your pointer, but rather just the pointer according to the header file: getPGMfile(iName1, img)

Comment: Thanks!  That helps.  Any idea why the width won't be read correctly?

Comment: Code:
`code`printf("\n width  = %d",(*img).width);
`code`printf("\n height = %d",(*img).height);
`code`printf("\n maxVal = %d",(*img).maxVal);
`code`printf("\n");

Console:
Reading image file: C:\\balloons.pgm
Type: 2
 width  = 0
 height = 480
 maxVal = 255

Answer (score 0):

The PGM format goes as

```
P5
wid ht
xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

where xxx are the raster values.  You need to get rid of each `getc` function before reading the width, or perform an `ungetc` when it fails to find the character you are looking for.  Then, the width will be read appropriately.